# user-authentication from remote site?

Tags: django, design-patterns, authentication

I am building a tool, in django, for a client's web site.

The tool I am building requires users to be signed in to an existing account.

User-authentication is handled by legacy software on another vendor's servers.

I can contact the programmer who wrote the legacy software (I am unsure of their development environment), but I am not sure what to ask for -- what hooks, api, rpc, etc. do I want?

Is there a design pattern for this type of situation?  And what features of django should I use or extend to make this as straightforward as possible?  [REMOTE_USER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/) *sounds* like the right thing, but I am not sure how I would use it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using jquery requests. You can send the username and password (encrypted, of course) to the remote site and get back a cookie/session key.

If you have access to the database, I'd also recommend doing that. For example, if the remote host is using MySQL, ask to have a view created for your user and then you can authenticate directly. With this approach, however, you may have to set up a MySQL connection outside of `settings.py`.

Comment: The other project is not necessarily done in Django. So I am afraid your MySQL solution is not possible.

Comment: Right. MySQL is language-independent so even if the other person is using the weirdest API known to man you'd still be able to query the server. On your machine, use python to get a database handle to the other machine. Then you can get and send requests that way.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

**1) API:** If they have released their API, it would be much more simpler, you authenticate user using their API.

**2) Expose Database:** If they don't have API, they should must give their access to their database so that you can go in and authenticate. But while doing this keep in mind several things: Django `authenticate()` won't work, because by default authenticate method authenticates again `auth_user` table. You can of course manually authenticate using your own logic but that would be  problem too: you have to create your own sessions and stuffs. So your option is to use `custom user models` (only available from Django 1.5) in Django.

I am sure other may have better solution than this.